# pass any pointer to a function for deleting

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to create a function that would accept a pointer to an instance of a class as an argument and then delete it. The problem is that I don't know beforehand what it will be deleting. Basically what I need is something like this:

```
void Foo(pointer* generic_pointer){
  //Some code here
  delete generic_pointer;
  //Some more code here
}
```

I thought of using void* but that's apparently very bad coding, and results in chaos.

Note: I have an object that is basically a loop and when it ends I need to create another object(of different class), which is also a loop, then delete the original. With delete this I could not start the desired loop so I thought I could delete it from the second object, but it might be started from any kind of object, so this is the only thing I could think of. Any other suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: I can't see how your initial motivation ("want to create a function that accepts and deletes anything") could result in anything *but* chaos.

Comment: There is such a function: `operator delete()`

Comment: @WhozCraig: No there isn't.

Comment: @KerrekSB True that. vector-delete not accounted for. I submit.

Comment: @WhozCraig: No, no, not even that. Totally wrong ball park. Think about *objects*.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't play ball anymore (not since college), so espouse among us the wisdom of the enlightened, whilst I prepare myself for the impending flogging.

Comment: @WhozCraig: `operator new()`/`operator delete()` are memory allocation functions. They don't construct/destroy objects. How are you going to call the destructor(s)?

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah, there you have it. *I don't* =P. If i was placement-new'ng the junk i'd manually fire them, but clearly thats out.

Comment: This sounds like an XY question, where we're asked how to do Y, when the actual problem is X - because the questioner thinks that Y is the solution to the problem...

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes, pretty much. In that case, chuck this question and make a new one about the actual problem?

Comment: Well, either that, or edit the question to match what you are really trying to do - but probably better to start a new question - accept one of the answers below saying "you can't do that" as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. The `delete` operator uses the type of the data to deduce the destructor to be called. If the type is `void*`, it can't deduce anything sensible. You may want to look into the smart pointers topic instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is very bad, casting to `void*` and passing that looses all type info and you'll end up in undefinedbehaviorland faster than it takes the program to compile.

Just do it the old-fashioned way and call `delete`. I don't see an advantage to calling `Foo(something)` over `delete something`.

Answer (score 0):

Smart pointers as it has been already said. Let smart pointer manage memory instead of You. Try to implement Your own smart pointers (for only You in educational aims). In the Internet You can find a lot of different ideas and implementations.

P. S.

> I thought of using void* but that's apparently very bad coding, and
>   results in chaos.

You sound like a crusader))) *There are not only black and white in C++.* Simply there are a lot of possibilities to use something incorrectly. Actually, there are some things that are really to be implemented using void* in order to look elegant, You just should hide them from users in implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Templates?

```
template<typename T>
void Foo<T>(T* p) {
  delete p;
}
```

Comment: Ouch: `int a[10]; Foo(a);`

Comment: @KerrekSB should be noted that it's not worse than `int a[10]; delete a;` - same problem. Surely, no advantage too, but that's another problem

Comment: @icepack: Right, but `delete a;` is clearly wrong, while it's non-obvious that a function whose express purpose is to delete something would contain such an invisible error.

Comment: I guess answering questions I should worry about re-enforcing the questioner's bad programming over answering their question. Point taken.

Comment: The passed pointer would invariably be a pointer to exactly one instance of a class (I don't know what class though).

Answer (score -1):

You could use templates to achieve this

```
template <class T>
void Foo(T* pointer){
//do your stuff
delete T;
}
```

Of course, this may not work for every case.

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/).

Comment: Same problem as Sean3k's...?!

Comment: @KerrekSB This is why I stated it might not work for every case.